# How to add/remove objects in a many to many relationship quickly using Spring data

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

My problem is this. I have 2 objects called `SeedRecord` and `AffiliateLink`. Both have a ManyToMany relation to each other. Affiliatelinks are linked with seedrecords based on a set of keywords that a user can characterize the affiliatelink product with. For example. If an affiliatelink product is useful for `tomato`, `cucumber`, `bellpepper` and `Climbing plant`. Then during the creation of the AffiliateLink object it is linked to all seedrecords that have one of these keyswords as a characteristic. So for example if the value of the column `CropName` of a particular seedrecord is `tomato` then the affiliatelink will be added to its collection.

This is all fine if the dataset is small, but adding an affiliatelink to the right seedrecords can become very laggy if there are over 2000 seedrecords of which 200 have the characteristic `tomato`. My `JpaRepository` will have to do 200 saves just to get the affiliatelink linked with all the proper seedrecords. This can take minutes!

Instead of sending 200 small save queries to the database i think things will be allot faster if i could put all the save actions in one big query instead. But i don't have an idea if thats possible with Spring Data. A delete action is just as laggy as a save action. Does anyone know of a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: i've managed to optimize by putting all the altered seedrecord objects in a list and then saving that list with the overloaded save function for Iterables. Now it takes about 7 seconds to create an affiliatelink and about 10 seconds to update it. Should i try to aim for higher speed?

Answer (score 0):

Well i've managed to reduce the time from 5 to 10 seconds when using all the different jparepository save methods to a nice 1.5 to 2 seconds using batch inserts with JDBC!

Heres my code should anyone be interested:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

    if (!affiliateLinkOwners.isEmpty()) {
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO seedrecord_affiliatelink (SEEDRECORD_ID, AFFILIATE_ID) VALUES (?,?)");
            for(long id: affiliateLinkOwners)
                    {
                        preparedStatement.setLong(1,id);
                        preparedStatement.setLong(2,affiliateLink.getId());
                        preparedStatement.addBatch();
                    }

            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            connection.commit();
            preparedStatement.close();
            connection.close();
            log.info(affiliateLinkOwners +"");
            log.info("the id is " + affiliateLink.getId());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                connection.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

heres the datasource itself that gets autowired:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource seedDataSource(){
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(driver);
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dataBaseUrl); 
    hikariConfig.setUsername(userName);
    hikariConfig.setPassword(password);
    hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
    hikariConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    return dataSource;
}
```

EDIT: I'm inserting only the Id's of the seedrecords and the affiliate id into the jointable